# Unity web player multi touch support

Tags: unity-game-engine, multi-touch, unityscript

Can Unity Web Player support Multi touch events?
From the samples I tested and from what I read it seems it doesn't support. All the Unity multitouch solutions I found were based on TUIO and TUIO doesn't seem to work in web player. Web player only seems to support mouse events.

So I want to know whether it's possible to add multi touch to objects in Unity web player. If so what is the path I should follow to implement multi touch support.

Any help on this is really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

david-demainlalune at TouchScript helped me with this by adding touch support to web player.

https://github.com/david-demainlalune/TuioToUnityWebPlayerDemo
https://github.com/InteractiveLab/TouchScript

But he suggests that this might not be a very good route to follow. Using the above I was able to add multi touch to the web player. But I decided to implement this as a Unity app without going for web player option since this was not reliable.

Comment: If you need more info please follow this https://github.com/InteractiveLab/TouchScript/issues/38

Answer (score 0):

Several of the PCs, laptops out there don't have a true multitouch, they have a simulated touch under the hood, which take the touchs as click events, so in that way simple click(tap) or two finger gestures should work on the web player.
Not sure what you want to achieve or which gestures you want to incorporate.

I have tested multitouch but in a windows build, no with the web player.

When you say doesn't seem to work is a confirmation or you haven't tested.

I suspect that TouchScript (TUIO) should work on most cases for advanced touch screens not cheap, non standard windows pc screens. The best bet is to code a script in some multitouch screens using the Input.GetTouches and the moving fwd to touchScript.

Also take a look at gestureworks.com they have a library that can be used for touch gestures in unity, aside from touch script is looks the more robust for me so far. I still have to tested.

So far I have asked unity folks and they have confirmed touch is working on windows surface in a windows build not sure with web player. Ask also there your question.

Also look at this discussion which are not related to web player but they list some workarounds.
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/220548/using-microsoft-surface-20-with-unity.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I have a 3D model in a Unity scene. I have used TouchScript to handle multitouch. When I build the Unity project as Mac or Windows standalone and run it on a Multi touch screen everything works well. But when I run the same thing using the web player multi touch gestures like pinch zoom doesn't work. When I pinch zoom the object it zooms the browser window not the object.